# Cloudinary File Upload Error

Tags: javascript, express, cloudinary, formidable

I'm writing a REST API on using Express.js. The API needs to accept a video file from the client and upload it to cloudinary. When I use the api to return the file back to the client (as a test) everything works perfectly. When I then try to upload the same file to cloudinary I get an error. the error says:

```
"file.match is not a function"
```

I'm not sure what file.match even is or why it is giving me a problem. If anyone else has had this issue how did you solve it?
Below is the code that is giving me issues:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var formidable = require('express-formidable');
var app = express();

app.use(formidable());

var routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/routes', routes);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Express server is listening on port ' + port);
});
```

routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var cloudinary = require('../cloudinary.js').cloudinary;
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
  cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.files, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

cloudinary.js

```
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: 'name',
  api_key: 'key',
  api_secret: 'secret'
});

module.exports.cloudinary = cloudinary;
```

Comment: since cloudinary.js is your own code, prefer you show that code as well

Comment: @Simon Ive added the code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. It was not a problem on Cloudinary's end. The key was to only send the location of the file.

WORKING routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var cloudinary = require('../cloudinary.js').cloudinary;
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
  var fileGettingUploaded = req.files.fileToUpload.path;

  cloudinary.uploader.upload(fileGettingUploaded, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify the `resource_type` as `video` -

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.files, 
    function(result) {console.log(result); },
    { resource_type: "video" });
```

If you're uploading images and videos you can use the `auto` as `resource_type`.

Comment: the same error still occurs, "file.match is not a function"

Comment: Can you please open a [support ticket](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) and share the video file for us to further investigate? 
Please reference this Post as well..

Comment: I did as you asked